# Share Volume Group

Tags: partitioning, samba, lvm, file-sharing

I have create a volume group X to which I have added 2 physical drives HDD1 and HDD2. What I want to do is to share this VG such that I can use is it as a single drive.

Can someone please explain how I can about this as, when I add the drives as logical volumes I can see the two "files" for the drives which can easily be deleted by mistake.

I know I can "protect" the "files" but is there a way to share a VG without the LV or can I hide the LV so they aren't shown? Perhaps calling them .HDD1 and .HDD2?

Right now I have no data on the VG so I will try anything suggested.

Thanks.

Comment: I can not tell from the obscure gibberish you posted. create volume group X the way you wish so that $it_just_works . Same with your $two_files you$protect on your $VG  and $LV and $HDD! and $HDD2 . If you want help with LVM you will need to post your configuration as well as relevant information on you drives, ie physical volumes, and logical volumes, and files.

Comment: Thanks for the sarcastic (and somewhat rude) reply but I managed to sort it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong was to format each individual logical volume (LV) which had previously been assigned to the virtual group (VG) which then prevented the entire VG being shared as a single "drive".

The solution, for me anyway, was to create the VG and assign the physical drives and then create a single LV which "spanned" the physical drives as a single file system rather than 2 drives with their own file system. It's a bit like a RAID 0 (or striped disks).

Comment: I see you fixed it the way I told you. As I said if you need assistance you need to post configuration details as I am not willing to take random guesses at your LVM configuration.

Comment: Interesting and an apology. I never got the fact you were telling me what to do as I completely misread your message and hence the reason I said it was somewhat rude. You'll have to excuse me as I'm totally new to LVM and as I used Webmin to set it all up I had no clue about the configuration files until I started reading deeper to find the solution.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, it is frustrating when you are new and have problems.